# Is it more secure to mutual authenticate in a single protocol?

Tags: authentication, mutual

I would like to know if, in a communication between two *peer* users A and B *with no central authority*, it is more secure to mutual authenticate both A to B and B to A applying a single protocol, rather than authenticate first A to B and then B to A. In the latter case, which attack could we have between the first and the second authentication?

Does there exist a protocol providing a "single-pass" mutual authentication between two peer users and with no central authority that is more secure than authenticate first one user to the other and then vice-versa?

Comment: Please elaborate more, what do you mean `authenticate first one user and then the other`.   Taking any chat apps as example,  each user always login to single system, with their local private cert to maintain the encryption, then the communication establish between the user.

Comment: @mootmoot I edited the question trying to clarify better the sentence that you highlighted and specifying that there is no central authority (so there is no "single system", but only 2 users that want to communicate via a generic protocol).

Comment: I would love to give an answer, but the question is so abstract that the only possibly answer is "It depends on the protocol". As written,  following both fit within your definition: A) a chat program where auth in each direction is independent, B) I show government ID at a doctor's office, then they mail me paper proof of the doctor's medical licence. I assume you're talking about the internet and auth involving cryptography? Can you explicitly say which protocol you're talking about so that it's possible to answer?

Comment: As mentioned by @Mike above, what `protocol` do you mean?  Take VPN as example, one side may host a VPN server and give certificate key to the trusted party, mutual trust is already established.   After VPN establish, authentication between A & B is via application layer.

Comment: @mootmoot Say if you can tell me if such a protocol exist you have indirectly answered to the question. I reformulated again the original post. Notice: the users are peers, let's say they are two hosts in internet with any kind of technology available, but no central authority, so no certificates.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth "I assume you're talking about the internet and auth involving cryptography" you assume right.

Comment: **You don't need a central server to apply PKI trust** . PGP is a good example.   A & B can issue a cert to each other, though it is counter intuitive.